# PHP phpseclib library and global variables vs referenced variables

Tags: php, function, global-variables, phpseclib

I'm having a strange little problem accessing an array inside a function using **global**.  I know I can try using a **reference** instead but I'd still like to understand why what I'm doing below doesn't work.

```
include "./phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php";
include "./phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php";
include "./phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php";

$keyArray = array();

function key_gen($exponent=65537, $bits=1024) {
    global $keyArray;

    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    define('CRYPT_RSA_EXPONENT', $exponent);
    $rsa->setHash("sha256");
    $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);

    extract($rsa->createKey($bits));
    $keyArray["clientPublicKey"] = $publickey;
    $keyArray["clientPrivateKey"] = $privatekey;
    $keyArray["clientPassPhrase"] = bin2hex(crypt_random_string(128));

    extract($rsa->createKey($bits));
    $keyArray["serverPublicKey"] = $publickey;
    $keyArray["serverPrivateKey"] = $privatekey;
    $keyArray["serverPassPhrase"] = bin2hex(crypt_random_string(128));
    print_r($keyArray);

}

key_gen();
print_r($keyArray);
```

produces the following:

```
Array
(
    [clientPublicKey] => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCWWmihVabPYOTMYTUUPwpUdcND
hI7k7F6cnbKeohzIZF6v82ZaieSPfO3QtQtL3pev/iagKZCLpC0NHvWSyV7EO5IT
od4uHFeJk97XwxSumPxamZ+deW8dOyCrFTDF9ibwe3Fq9dyLQ4yhjsr73DgAvAOR
9YfvV5xypZ+5mWa95wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    [clientPrivateKey] => -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    [clientPassPhrase] => 1841479148f770551e3cd4ce442789c0870a73235309bf07de00f216f6aa1d6aecd070c94ef175446d00d036c9a61dba14da41985ecff69a8922e95d1807970960dc8696c14ba630328f04c05c578dd16e3bf915ae13c0c568fa0ddffbae08a2d7092ebcc7222e07949258b0fc05cf30b23ba7ca4c40b3910bbf016feac7e6a5
    [serverPublicKey] => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUhxVLlpOTVNOhDUnFrqihNH8b
grXhWzl0IpsW3pnvwo+fQTwmBSKsCXKMd7k7QVYQ4/amu+tCC5ZTe8ngQbSQHSBd
jLQqg+C9AHucQw+HIkKrKaPvTD32m2QSIMvARLdJij/3ziT/3hB68pbwZYWpiAUr
/lujXvUoeTzasZWpxQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    [serverPrivateKey] => -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    [serverPassPhrase] => 7db35ef1985e8313c057441d5445fcb16426836cc1d127a06d578cfb4740d5be66b1cf7c60f9dc501b3059fe150173d4fc662f2c6579b6a20d48f44f9b8e55bd8529f88d72bb5ec57e07e58033a95baa621313cefa4439d1c22961bc0d9026f4582ad654cabb55224c948cb983954cf2564bb8f567fb9b081b333feafdba7bae
)
Array
(
)
```

Notice the second attempt to print_r($keyArray) contains nothing.  Why exactly, does it have something to do with the way the content from phpseclib is being stored in $keyArray?

Comment: Hide your private keys.

Comment: @sectus - he's creating a key from scratch. You could run that script a thousand times and, in theory, you'd get a thousand different private keys. I'd hazard to guess that he's not using those keys in a real world scenario.

Comment: @Vince - Works fine for me on PHP 5.4.7. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @neubert, sure, you are right.

Comment: @neubert PHP v5.4.21, but no worries, I'm just going to access the array using the &$keyArray method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that code placed inside some function via include. There two scopes: inside function and outside function. But they are local both. You should add `global $keyArray;`before `$keyArray = array();`.

But it's better to use this array as function argument.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is correct. When I run this code from the command line the second print_r has all the data. I think with the way you are running it the definition of $keyArray = array() and the final print_r are not done in global scope. But you should obviously be passing &$keyArray as a third argument to the function.

Comment: @Cuagau, is it comment to the question?

Comment: @sectus Sorry Sectus, I'm not very good at the lingo.  What do you mean when you say 'use this array as function argument'?  Do you mean set the calls up like this: `$keyArray = array(); function key_gen(&$keyArray, $exponent=65537, $bits=1024) {...} key_gen($keyArray);` And not to use `global $keyArray` at the top of my template?  Or do both?

Comment: Oh, yeah. There is two ways: pass as reference, and just return it.